# Entity Framework Update existing foreign Key reference to another

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys

I have two tables Team_DATA and Driver_PROFILE_DATA in an SQL database.  For every driver_profile there can be many teams.

So there's a one-to-many relation on the driver_profile to team_data table.  I want to update a team_data foreign key reference in the Driver_profile table of an already existing record to another team_data record that already exists.

I want to do this using entity framework. Here what I want: having a list of teams to select from, finding the record in the team_data table and updating it's FK in the driver_profile appropriately.

So in the code below, the passed parameter is the newly selected team out of the team_data table.

Now I need it to update it FK reference in the Driver_profile table.

Here's what I've got:

UPDATE: Code Updated.  It does not save it to database, even if I call savechanges.  No errors.

```
 public Driver_PROFILE_DATA GetSelectedTeam(string team)
    {
        ObjectQuery<Team_DATA> td = raceCtxt.Team_DATA;
        ObjectQuery<Driver_PROFILE_DATA> drpr = raceCtxt.Driver_PROFILE_DATA;

        var selteam = from t in td where t.Team_Name == team select t;

        Team_DATA newteam = new Team_DATA();

        newteam = selteam.Select(x => x).First();

        // get driver_profile with associated team_data
        var data = from a in raceCtxt.Driver_PROFILE_DATA.Include("Team_DATA") select a;
        // put it in driver_profile entity
        profileData = data.Select(x => x).First();

        profileData.Team_DATAReference.Attach(newteam);

        return profileData;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework should give you a nice Association between the two classes, Update the references as you would using POCOs and stay away from the ID values.

Something like:

```
newTeam.Profile.Teams.Remove(profileData);  // separate from old Profile
profileData.Teams.Add(newTeam);
```

#### EDIT:

I made a little test, it is sufficient to set the reference to the Parent object:

```
newTeam.Profile = profileData;
```

Comment: so can you give me an example?

Comment: thanks for the new acronym: POCO: Plain Old CLR Object! Hehe didn't know that!

Comment: I was thinking: Plain Old C# Object, but maybe CLR is better.

Comment: Show the new code, show the association properties and define 'not working'

Comment: @Henk: Thanks! That works, as it changes the reference to the child object, but the changes do not get persisted to the database when calling SaveChanges on it.  Any ideas?

Comment: Checking entitystate of newteam and profiledata after changing FK references, they are both in 'unchanged' state, so why would that be?

Comment: Check the mapping of your FKs, in my simple test the changes _did_ get saved.